# How can I change the Table class names using the by extending jOOQ's DefaultGeneratorStrategy?

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I am using the jooq codgen gradle plugin to change the naming convention for generated tables to include `Table` at the end of the class name. However, I am not sure how to distinguish a table from a schema in the generator.

My naming override is:

```
@Override
public String getJavaClassName(Definition definition, Mode mode) {
    String result = super.getJavaClassName(definition, mode);
    if (mode == Mode.DEFAULT) {
        result += "Table";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there a way to determine If the current object extends `TableImpl` or maybe I need to take a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `instanceof` checks on your `definition`, like this:

```java
@Override
public String getJavaClassName(Definition definition, Mode mode) {
    String result = super.getJavaClassName(definition, mode);
    if (mode == Mode.DEFAULT && definition instanceof TableDefinition) {
        result += "Table";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you need to implement a custom `GeneratorStrategy` in one Maven module and use it in another. This is because JOOQ's `generate` goal runs before the Java compiler runs in the same project.